# I want to send an email to user with html template in mvc.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to send an email to user  with html template in mvc.net i am trying to bind html template but it goes simple mail template is not showing, here is my code.

**here is Controller Code**

```
 private void SendActivationEmail(AddCenter center)
{
    Guid activationCode = Guid.NewGuid();
     TrueScanEntities db  = new TrueScanEntities();
      db.UserActivations.Add(new UserActivation
    {
        ID = center.Center_ID,
        ActivationLink = activationCode
    });
    db.SaveChanges();

    using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("sender@gmail.com", center.Center_Email))
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplate/EmailTemplate.html"));
        mm.Subject = "Account Credential";
        string body = "Hello " + center.CenterIncharge + ",";
        body += "<br /><br />Your Account Credential is given below" + "<br/>" + "User Name"+":"+"<br/>"+ center.Center_Email+"<br/>"+"Password"+":"+ center.Center_Passwrd + ".";

        //body += "<br /><br />Please click the following link to activate your account";
        //body += "<br /><a href = '" + string.Format("{0}://{1}/Admin/Activation/{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, activationCode) + "'>Click here to activate your account.</a>";
        body += "<br /><br />Thanks";
        mm.Body = body;
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "123");
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);
    }
}
```

here is a HTML template i want to send user their userid and password in given template.

what should i do in html template?

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container-for-gmail-android" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="100%" style="background:repeat-x url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/swu-filepicker/4E687TRe69Ld95IDWyEg_bg_top_02.jpg) #ffffff;">
            <center>
                <img src="../ATemplate/assets/images/newly.png" />

            </center>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" width="100%" style="background-color: #f7f7f7;" class="content-padding">
            <center>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" class="w320">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="header-md">
                            Thank You For Registration <!--In [client]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="free-text">Kindly retain below Registration Details for logging in future.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="mini-block-container">
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse:separate !important;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="mini-block">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-bordered">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                <td>[name]</td>
                                            </tr>


                                            <tr>
                                                <th>User Name</th>
                                                <td>[user]</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Email ID</th>
                                                <td>[email]</td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Password</th>
                                                <td>[pass]</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Reg Date</th>
                                                <td>[date]</td>
                                            </tr>


                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" width="100%" style="background-color: #f7f7f7; height: 100px;">
            <center>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" class="w320">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 25px 0 25px">
                            <strong>Coppyright </strong><a href="https://www.Whizsoftwares.com" target="_blank"> Whizsoftwares.com</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the mail is sending like this:

[image]

but i want to bind this template:

[image]

Comment: "i am trying to bind html template". You create the `reader` but then do not use it. Your email currently contains the simple HTML you placed in your `body` variable. It's not really clear what you wanted to do with it. Perhaps you can try to actually render the partial view using a model and get back the HTML into a string, or perhaps use some other kind of templating like XSLT.

Comment: What is the email content you get now? Please add a screenshot.

Comment: @Habeeb i have added screenshot in above links

Comment: From your screenshot, its obvious that your HTML is working only that the styles are not picked up. Are you trying the final email on gmail? If so try sending to some other email clients like outlook and see if the styles do appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the template as a string and then replace the text you want and the email body needs to be proper HTML starting and closing with  tag. You should also use the string builder to construct your template.

```
var emailBody = new StringBuilder("<html><body>");
emailBody.Append(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplate/EmailTemplate.html")));
emailBody.Replace("[name]", ... );
emailBody.Append("</body></html>");

mm.Body = emailBody.ToString();
```

Comment: thank you for commenting.Can you elaborate your answer more deeply??

Comment: I'm not sure which part of the answer you don't understand?